# How to `yarn run start` providing custom modules location

Tags: yarnpkg

Here is my problem, I  constructed a dockerfile launching `yarn install` from a folder where a `package.json` and `yarn.lock` are present (they have been taken from the project I have to setup yarn dependencies for, this project is inside a deconnected server).
Then, I run bash into container image and uploaded the created folder `node_modules`, and put it into the deconnected server, where project is present, at root folder project.
But then, when I launched `yarn start` from root folder, it says that it cannot find `rescripts` despite of the fact that folder `@rescripts` is present into `node_modules`.
I tried `NODE_PATH=./node_modules yarn start` without any success.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think i get what i want with :
https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/

I create a cache folder with all `tar.gz` dependencies downloaded.
But if i remove `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, and run `yarn install --offline --cache-folder npm-packages-offline-cache/`, I got error saying it could not find proper dependance in cache folder. It's like it cannot recognize any `tar.gz` inside. Any help will be welcome.

Regars